Use iOS library in KMP project
I am importing pure iOS libraries into a KMP project using native CocoaPods Gradle plugin.
For example:
cocoapods {
   ...
   pod("FirebaseCrashlytics") {
       version = "11.6.0"
       extraOpts = listOf("-compiler-option", "-fmodules")
   }
}

I can use them without any problems inside my shared module (iosMain).
Then I build the shared framework using multiplatform-swiftpackage library:
multiplatformSwiftPackage {
    swiftToolsVersion("5.9")
    distributionMode { local() }
    buildConfiguration { debug() }
    outputDirectory(File(rootProject.projectDir, "swiftpackage"))
    targetPlatforms {
        iOS { v("16") }
    }
}

and import it into Xcode using Swift Package Manager.
I can build the iOS app successfully but while running it crashes with this exception:
dyld[53857]: Library not loaded: @rpath/FirebaseCrashlytics.framework/FirebaseCrashlytics
  Referenced from: <14169435-4CE9-3CBB-9344-F647245BBB78>

I'm getting the same error on every library I've tried.
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

FirebaseCrashlytics was added to your Kotlin build, but those dependencies aren't carried over through SPM. Add them to Xcode directly.
